# SqlException: Syntax Error Near 'GO'

Tags: sql-server-2008, dbcontext

I am having trouble sending a SQL statement through a DbContext using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`.

I am trying to execute

```
CREATE TABLE Phones([Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Number] [int],[PhoneTypeId] [int])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Phones] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Phones_Id]  
    DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO
```

This fails with the error string

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

However running that exact statement in SSMS runs without errors?  Any issues I need to resolve regarding the default constraint throught the DbContext.  I have see problems with people using constraints and not having IsDbGenerated set to true.  I am not sure how that would apply here though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) is not a part of SQL, so it can't be executed with ExecuteSqlCommand().  Think of GO as a way to separate batches when using Management Studio or the command-line tools.  Instead, just remove the GO statements and you should be fine.  If you run into errors because you need to run your commands in separate batches, just call ExecuteSqlCommand() once for each batch you want to run.

Answer (score 5):

I know, necroposting is bad maner, but may be this post would save someone's time. As it was mentioned in Dave's post, GO is not a part of SQL, so we can create little workaround to make it work

```
            var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("initialization.sql");
            var parts = text.Split(new string[] { "GO" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (var part in parts) { context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(part); }

            context.SaveChanges();
```

In this case your commands would be splitted and executed without problems

Answer (score 4):

Dave Markle beat me to it. In fact, you can change "GO" to [any other string](http://vadivel.blogspot.com/2011/10/go-batch-separator.html) to separate batches.

An alternative implementation here is to use SMO instead of the Entity Framework. There is a useful method there called [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.executenonquery.aspx) that I think will make your life a lot simpler. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx) is a good implementation example.

Comment: That is true for SSMS, however even if you change the batch separator in SSMS the code above will still choke on the `GO`.

Comment: One note that I want to add.  If like me, you often want some kind of return value from your queries that you are passing via SMO, be aware that ExecuteWithResults will return exceptions when it runs into GO and ALTER statements.  I found this out a little while ago, and ended up just putting an option to ExecuteNonQuery on our UI that gets checked at script run time.